# Can I integrate Okta SSO in windows 8 apps (metro apps)?

Tags: windows-8, single-sign-on, okta

I have to work on an windows 8 app (metro app) where I need to implement Okta SSO feature. So is there any api available for the same and how Active directory authentication will work on this?

Answer (score 0):

Okta provides robust integration with Active Directory. A good place to start learning about integration options is with the Okta Help Center and a good document to start with is the [Overview of Directories and On Premise Infrastructure](https://support.okta.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/28049648-Overview-of-Directories-and-On-Premises-Infrastructure?id=kA0F0000000AY1z&q=Active%20Directory&l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle).

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for the reply. But my question is how to use Okta in windows 8 metro apps?